# Where clause when variable is false doesn't consider that into the SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have something that I don't quite understand, I have the solution, but I don't know why and it's driving me a bit crazy

Controller

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

$transfer = Transfer::where('ticket_id', $last_ticket)->where('event_id', 36)->where('buyer', $user_email)->first();

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();

dd($queries);
```

Result

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `transfers` where `ticket_id` = ? and `event_id` = ? and `buyer` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:3 [
      0 => false
      1 => 36
      2 => "[email protected]"
    ]
    "time" => 0.36
  ]
]
```

Situation:
`$last_ticket` in the DB is unique and never `null`, empty or `false`.

In my example `$last_ticket` is `false`, but in the DB there's no any `false`, why do I still get results?

Is it because whenever one where condition is false, it doesn't take that into the equation?

So the question is:
How can I do to receive the correct results meaning: if $last_ticket is false then no results, and if it has some data, then return the row result restricted by $last_ticket

One option could be to put `if($last_ticket == false){$last_ticket='randomInexistentString_ag4dh&2g32y4t'}` so it's not null or zero but I don't think it's the prettier way to go

Comment: Can you please provide with the "transfers" table schema, and specific with "ticket_id" column datatype and constraints?

Comment: What's the ticket_id field's value in the returned resultset? (My guess that it is 0).

Comment: @Shadow is false probably same as 0

Comment: I'm interested in the returned value, not the parameter you supplied. That would tell us what's going on.

Comment: ah sorry, the returned value you mean is also false as per debug result in the post.. or are you asking another value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A zero in MySQL always matches any string that doesn't start with a digit - this is because it wants both sides of the comparison to be of the same type, so it converts the string to a number, and any string that doesn't start with a number evaluates to `0` automatically.

Now, you're not feeding it a `0` - but you're feeding it a `false`, and in MySQL, that's not a true boolean but actually a `0`.

Without knowing exactly what your database looks like, I'd say this is the most likely explanation.

There are ways around this, for instance you could use the `->when()` chaining on Eloquent:

```
Transfer::where('event_id', 36)
        ->where('buyer', $user_email)
        ->when($last_ticket, function ($query) use ($last_ticket) {
            $query->where('ticket_id', $last_ticket);
        })
        ->first();
```

(Taken from memory, syntax may be a little bit off. Thanks to Rick James for correction in comments.)

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know about the 0, and if I feed it with null?

Comment: I think it's the same thing but I'm honestly not sure by heart.

Comment: Extra points ;) I added a question to the same topic, how to do to return none if last_ticket is zero or null

Comment: Your extra question is a little odd - it's a pure if condition, so why don't you just do `if ($last_ticket) { do things } else { don't do things }`?

Comment: @JoelHinz - No.  A zero matches any string _that does not start with digits_.  In converting the string to a number, it consumes leading digits if they are there.

Comment: @TrOnNe - `ticket_id = NULL` does not work like you think it might -- you need to say `ticket_id IS NULL`.

Comment: @RickJames How is starting with a digit different from starting with a number? English is my fourth language so I may be missing something here which is not related to MySQL.

Comment: @JoelHinz - ("Number" and "digit", _in this context_ are interchangeable.) 
 This is what struck me as 'wrong':  "A zero in MySQL always matches any string".  But then you contradicted it with:  "... any string that doesn't start with a number evaluates to 0 ...".  For example, zero matches `"abc"` and `"000abc"`, but not `"123abc"` and not `"0123abc"`.

Comment: @RickJames Ah, of course - yes, I can't believe I didn't catch that on multiple readthroughs. Thanks a lot, will edit appropriately!

Answer (score 2):

Redesign the UI.  If something should be left out of the query, then *do not include it* in the query.

That is, build the `WHERE` clause dynamically so that, when "false" is supplied, it becomes

```
WHERE `event_id` = ? and `buyer` = ?
```

I don't know about Laravel, but in PHP, I would build an array of things to `AND` together, then construct the `WHERE`:

```
$ands = array();
if (...)  $ands[] = "ticket_id = ...";
if (...)  $ands[] = "event_id = ...";
if (...)  $ands[] = "buyer = ...";

if (empty($ands))
    $where = '';
else
    $where = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $ands);

$sql = "SELECT ... $where ...";
```

Note that it easily handles any or all or none of the items being omitted.

Comment: In laravels query builder you can pass an array of contidions: `->where(['ticket_id' => 7, 'event_id' => 5])`. See first comment [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L487). You should even be able to pass an empty array, so you won't need to check `if (empty($ands))`.